# Why do I have this warning when submiting my FireFox Add-On?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

This the message I get :

```
Usage of non-SDK interface

Warning: This SDK-based add-on uses interfaces that aren't part of the SDK.
resources/lib/main.js
8
9
var {Cc, Ci, Cr} = require("chrome");
var data = require('sdk/self').data;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you've used a method in your code that is available but is not part of the public API.

This means that your code will work but isn't supported in the long term; the method you're relying on may be changed without warning in any given update of Firefox, whereas methods in the public API will be fully supported for longer (and if they do want to deprecate something, in the public API you'll get plenty of warning before it's actually removed).

As for what exactly it is that you've done to trigger it, I can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: How or Where should I Look for documentation on support feature?